# Replace value in list with calculated property powershell

Tags: powershell, calculated-property

I have two lists in powershell that have the following structure:

Variable = $serviceusage2

| ServiceName | ActivatedUsers |
| --- | --- |
| Serivce1 | 24 |
| Service2 | 4 |
| Service3 | 10 |

Variable $spdata

| PlanID | SerivcePlanName | ServicePlanDisplayName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GUID1 | Service1 | Nice Name for Service 1 |
| GUID2 | Service2 | Nice Name for Service 2 |
| GUID3 | Service3 | Nice Name for Service 3 |

The ServiceName and ServicePlan name match in each list.

I'm trying to build out a single list that will add a new column using the ServicePlanDisplayName based on match of the service name using the claculated properties of select-object

I've tried:

```
$serviceuage2 | Select-Object Servicename, @{ n= 'FriendlyName'; e= {$_ | ForEach-Object { @($SPdata.Servicename[$_.Servicename]).ServicePlanDisplayName}}},ActivatedUsers
```

and some variations of that, but I'm either getting no response or an error saying the value of the parameter is null.

```
Select-Object : The value of a parameter was null; one of the following types was expected: {System.String,
System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock}.
At line:1 char:17
+ ... viceuage2 | Select-Object $_.Servicename, @{ n = 'FriendlyName';e= {$ ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DictionaryKeyUnknownType,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `$spdata` is an array of objects, first convert it into a hash table, for this `Group-Object -AsHashtable` helps greatly:

```
$spdata = $spdata | Group-Object SerivcePlanName -AsHashtable
```

Once you have your lookup table you can do the calculated property this way:

```
$serviceusage2 | Select-Object Servicename, @{ N='FriendlyName'; E={ $spdata[$_.Servicename].ServicePlanDisplayName }}, ActivatedUsers
```

Comment: That worked.   Small Typo in the PS (but that's due to my typo in the above).   Thanks!